# Estimating trainer 'effort above the flat' by heart rate + cadence

Tags: trainer, cadence, heart-rate, performance-tracking

A question popped into my head after yesterday's trainer ride.

First, a long-winded preamble.

As I pointed out [in this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/39221/speed-to-power-calc-on-a-basic-magnetic-trainer), I usually set the trainer up so that a 5l cask of wine just moves the pedal from horizontal in 'top' (48:14).

In that configuration, my average HR will stay in the 130s at a cadence of 80 in 'top'.

If I ride on the road, my HR seldom gets above 130 except on hills or if I crank up the cadence to 100+ in top (on the flat): I am loath to ride at any decent speed on the road because I am usually surrounded by people of median IQ driving 1500kg+ steel boxes - and I don't trust any of them not to kill me (assuming they're not actually trying to).

Yesterday I didn't have a full cask anywhere (I've been off the grog for six weeks, on a bet), so I just cranked it up until I couldn't move the pedal using my hand when seated next to the trainer.

This provided 'ample' resistance, to say the least: 2 minutes in, my HR was in the 140s although my cadence was only in the low 70s - and not in top gear, either - the average speed for the workout was 22km/hr.

Doing 'sprints' (15sec bursts at a cadence of > 130 in top) was almost the end of me.

Half an hour later, my HRM said I'd exerted ~500kcal over 10.7km, with an average HR of 148 and a peak HR of 166. The kcal count is about right for workouts where I do more sprints, and at a significantly higher average speed (i.e., a distance travelled of ~17km, reflected by an average cadence of 80 in top: cadence maps directly to speed via gear ratio).

So if I expressed this as "*what is X in 48:X, to get that distance at a cadence of 80*", the answer is "a little over 22". In other words, riding on (roughly) the 4th-highest gear, my HR was 10% higher than it usually is riding at the same cadence in top.

That got me thinking: rather than work out the effort above my 'wine cask' resistance level, I ought to be able to work out the 'effort above **flat**' implied by the level of resistance I dial in, by

- finding decent-sized bit of car-free flat (say, a 1km loop somewhere);
- going around it at a series of stable cadences (in top) and HRs (say, cadences of 80 and 100; HRs of 120, 130, and 140) each for a few minutes.

For each cadence, I would then know my 'steady state' HR on the flat (it will stabilise after a few minutes); for each HR, I will know what speed/cadence on the flat is consistent with that HR.

So if my HR is, say 10% higher (on average across the workout) than it was on the flat 'benchmark' for the same cadence in the same gear, I would chalk that one up as being '10% above the flat'. (I'm not pretending that's a 10% *incline*, or even a 10 *degree* incline; just that it's objectively 10% 'harder').

I realise that over time it would be expected that performance would get better, so there would be a need to periodically re-assess the 'flat' performance.

So finally the question: **has this sort of analysis already been done and put up on the web somewhere**?

I've googled terms I think might yield results, but haven't found a sausage. It seems to me that performance-metrics boffins would probably have solved this already (assuming it's an issue that has benefit for performance monitoring, which I reckon it does) so my search terms are probably a bit pants.

Comment: Heart rate is sensitive to temperature, hydration status, duration, and fatigue, which makes your quest for an answer here even more difficult than for your [previous question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/39221/speed-to-power-calc-on-a-basic-magnetic-trainer).

Comment: How old are you?  (approx if you prefer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That got me thinking: rather than work out the effort above my 'wine
>   cask' resistance level, I ought to be able to work out the 'effort
>   above flat' implied by the level of resistance I dial in

What you are attempting to do is calibrate your heart-rate on the indoor trainer to real-world riding - and this is far too complicated. Since there are so many variables to consider.
Heart-rate is an indicator and not as accurate a measure as a power-meter. Your heart-rate can vary for the same effort over the same terrain depending on diet, recovery, fatigue and so on. Also riding outdoors there is the issue of weather conditions also - which can be for you or against you.

Another factor I can see is - although your indoor trainer attempts to provide a "road-like feel" - and all indoor trainers boast of providing the most realistic road-like feel. It will have a spin-down - that is the period which the trainer continues to spin after pedaling has stopped. This represents resistive inertia - good ones have excellent resistance and also take longer to spin down and have a nice "feel" to them when riding. So - your indoor trainer will not be a perfect representation of real world riding.

And don't forget - perceived effort - for me - indoors is often greater than perceived effort outdoors.
I know for fact - my indoor power stats are lower than my outdoor power stats.

Personally, I would be setting the resistance at a single-level and changing through the gears to alter resistance. Looking purely at speed as a measure of your power - and using this as a basis for training. Might be a bit tricky - because it is speed and not power (everything is watts these days!). But you can combine this with your heart-rate data to know your speed and HR zones for training.

Comment: I've been toying with buying a decent ('smart', Zwift-compatible) trainer for a while - until then I was trying to do things using shoestrings and sticky-tape. I was going to go 'all in' and buy a Wahoo KickR until it was made clear to me that I would need to buy another bike (because my gearset is incompatible with a KickR: my bike's a $220, 15kg, clunker). Plus, **The Lovely** wouldn't give Royal Assent to the purchase until I 'got some time up' on the current trainer (a $69 Aldi job) - today she gave me the all-clear, so I'm allowed to order a bKool Smart Pro.

Comment: That's great news :-) 
Check compatibility of the BKool here
https://support.zwift.com/hc/en-us/articles/206332985--Setting-up-a-Bkool-trainer-with-ANT-FE-C

Comment: I eventually went for a Wahoo KickR and a new bike (a Merida Scultura). My Zwift avatar looks buff (6'1" and 104kg, as imagined by a bike-happy coder-geek, in Wahoo kit) and all my questions about power and what-not are superfluous because now I know the answer: big fat old blokes can put half-decent power to ground ('tempo' FTP of 271 - i.e., can do 285W for 20 minutes without getting HR anywhere near 'threshold')... but I'm totally pants at hills. Just like in real life - but with no "insecurity wagons" (SUVs) trying to kill me.

Answer (score 2):

Might I enquire your age?   This answer will be a bit vague without that, but you can work it out backwards.

The rule of thumb says that your max heart rate is 220-(your age in years)    I'm 40, so 180 would be my "100%" heart rate.

This table shows cycling
[image]

This chart shows the "zones"

[image]

So your 130 BPM is likely to be the "weight loss zone" for under 50 or the Aerobic zone for over 50.

Back to cycling, my "tempo" zone would be 70-80% of 180, so 126-144 BPM.

Here's a short ride from last week - heart rate was above 160 for at least half, and a peak of 173.  That translates to higher threshhold and into VO2, which is pretty good, giving speeds of mid 30km/h to a peak of 42 km/h.  https://www.strava.com/activities/757787829/analysis

---

So to summarise - 130 BPM is a good "endurance" workout.   You'd need to be doing that speed for a couple hours, and frankly that's boring on a trainer.

If you're dead against training on the road, try riding at a velodrome or some other kind of off-road track.  An athletic track may work, or around the local park?

If you can work a decent climb into your trip then that will be excellent exercise.  Use a tool like strava to measure your gains, cos it never feels faster.

Comment: Its not a great answer but too long for a comment, and we can't post images in comments either.

Comment: I'm 51; the 130 is the average for a *HIIT* workout where each of the "sprints" gets my HR to 'max', with a sprint/rest split of 30-on, 90-off, usually done 10 times with steady-state (HR in the 120s) for warm-up and cool down - that gets me to 30 mins. Every now and then I do something more 'constant' for an hour (knowing that I won't wizz properly for two days: no amount of seat- and knick-padding can prevent my 104kg from causing pressure on the (ahem) 'contact' region... the legendary 'scranus'). I'm moving to a Zwift-capable 'smart' trainer in the next month or so.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I do use Strava sometimes - the last workout (done with fewer, shorter, more intense sprints than usual to check the correspondence between sensors) is at https://www.strava.com/activities/759984056 (the peak speed measure is clearly a glitch!).

Comment: @GT. Been there - anytime I ride the other-half's bike, I have to stand up almost the whole way.  You might benefit from trialing other saddles.

Comment: I've tried every saddle type from 'big arse' saddles (chafe!!) to the ones that have two separate pads and no 'taint-destroyer' bits (that just felt weird, even on the trainer). I measured my sit-bone gap using the 'corrugated cardboard' tip (c-to-c was 140mm - I have Māori bum-bones... **World Champs, Cuz!**) and got a bike fit. A good mate who rides 'proper' races (A-grade seniors on a $10k bike) suggested a useful solution: "**HTFU, old man**". The statistical risk of permanent taint-related damage from bike-riding is near-zero, but that's cold comfort "the day after".